# Why does the kinetic coefficient of friction increase with a greater incline?

Tags: experimental-physics, mass, friction

I have been conducting an experiment in which I increase the angle of a wooden plank and drag a mass up attached to a force meter at a constant speed. A reading is taken, and this is subtracted by the component of gravity down the slope to give the friction force. This friction force is then divided by the normal force to give the coefficient of friction.
Confusingly, the coefficient of friction seems to (linearly) increase as the angle of the ramp is increased. As per predictions, the friction force decreases with an increase in angle of the ramp, but the friction coefficient increases. Is this a case of random/experimental error or is my understanding of the friction coefficient wrong?

Comment: Your method seems correct in  principle. Did you repeat the experiment several times at each angle and take an average to reduce the effect of random errors ? It would help if you showed your measurements and calculations for, say, two different angles so that we can see how your are calculating the component of the object's weight down the slope, and how you are calculating the normal force.

Comment: I have solved this problem. Kinetic friction coefficient remains constant regardless of incline. The "linear increase" observed presumably falls within the absolute uncertainty values measured. As normal force decreases, so does friction, deeming friction coefficient constant.